# Word or phrase expressing [pretentiousness of intentional/efforted design]?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

I am trying to find a word that expresses the pretentiousness of an obvious design, or maybe the feelings of disgust/disdain associated with such pretentiousness. Something like the feeling you might get from an affected art piece or performance. I feel like "pretentious" is probably the closest word, but I think it's vague/general enough term that further explanation is required to describe the sensation.

**An example usage:** "While Osamu's novel about the waning cultural influence of aristocratic families in in postwar Japan was generally well received by critics, the book's title *The Setting Sun* was often criticized for its [pretentiousness of intentional/efforted design]" Where "The Setting Sun" is an obvious, even gross metaphor for the book's theme.

Comment: Please add an example usage sentence for single word requests.

Comment: You can talk about the *latest and greatest* redesign.  Also, the person who made this decision *jumped on the workplace reorganization bandwagon*.  Some equivalent phrases to *pretentious* are *politically correct* and *modernistic*.

Comment: I guess they think an annulus engenders annualized growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **pompous** as an adjective, or **pompousness** as a noun.

> characterized by an ostentatious display of dignity or importance

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pompous?s=t

In your examples:

> the book's title *The Setting Sun* was often criticized for its **pompousness**.

or

> the office design was widely scorned because of its **pompous** design.

Comment: Nice! Not sure why I didn't think of that, though I think it works better for the first example than the second.